# Sandbox rest api getting "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR" with refund operation

Tags: paypal

I do a full refund and get this error message.

```
    RefundRequest refund = new RefundRequest();
    Sale sale = new Sale();
    sale.setId(paymentId);

    try {
        sale.refund(context, refund);
    } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
        throw new PaymentException(e);
    }
```

`response-code: 500 details: name: INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR   message: An internal service error occurred.    details: null   debug-id: ddc5e8373a92c information-link: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to refund the payment using PAY ID ( PAY-XXXX ). You will need to use resulted transaction id for processing the refund.

Please run the refund by passing the transaction id like below:

https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/4JXXXXXXXXXXX2H/refund